# Como pegar dados de um JSON com Python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

Estou pegando dados de um JSON. Só que estou tendo um problema.

```
{  
    "atividade_principal":[  
        {  
            "text":"Atividades de televisão aberta",
            "code":"60.21-7-00"
        }
    ],
    "data_situacao":"03/11/2005",
    "nome":"GLOBO COMUNICACAO E PARTICIPACOES S/A"
```

Eu consigo pegar os dados do `nome` e `data_situacao`. Só que ao pegar o dado da `atividade_principal`, acaba vindo tudo que está dentro e quero apenas o `text` e `code`.

Estou usando esse código em Python para pegar os dados. Consigo dessa forma pegar o nome.

```
 objeto = json.loads(objeto_texto)
 print = (objeto['nome'])
```

`objeto` é o JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para saber como ler e manipular um JSON, fica mais fácil quando entendemos a sua [sintaxe](http://json.org/):

- o que está entre colchetes (`[]`) é um array: uma lista de vários elementos
- o que está entre chaves (`{}`) é um objeto: um conjuntos de pares chave-valor

Seu objeto tem a chave `atividade_principal`, cujo valor é um array (pois está delimitado por `[]`).

O primeiro (e único) elemento deste array é um objeto (pois está delimitado por `{}`). E este objeto, por sua vez, contém as chaves `text` e `code`.

Então basta pegar o primeiro elemento do array, e em seguida pegar as chaves `text` e `code`:

```
import json

objeto_texto = """
{
  "atividade_principal": [
    {
      "text": "Atividades de televisão aberta",
      "code": "60.21-7-00"
    }
  ],
  "data_situacao": "03/11/2005",
  "nome": "GLOBO COMUNICACAO E PARTICIPACOES S/A"
}
"""

objeto = json.loads(objeto_texto)
atividade = objeto['atividade_principal'][0]

print(atividade['text']) # Atividades de televisão aberta
print(atividade['code']) # 60.21-7-00
```

No código acima, `objeto['atividade_principal']` retorna o array correspondente à chave `atividade_principal`.

Em seguida eu uso `[0]` para pegar o primeiro elemento do array (que no caso é o objeto que contém as chaves `text` e `code`). A partir daí eu consigo pegar o valor de cada um separadamente.

---

<sup>*Repare também que no JSON que você colocou faltou a chave de fechamento (`}`) no final, que eu adicionei no código acima.*</sup>